# How to log out a user when they update the app

Tags: react-native, react-redux, logout

Maven,

I have an app in react native and redux. I want to log out the users when they update the app from any of the stores. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can use a library such as `react-native-version-number` (https://github.com/APSL/react-native-version-number) to find your app's version number. Store the version in your state. Then, on app startup, check if the currentVersionNumber > the version number in the state. If so, reset the state.

Comment: worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to save the version number in AsyncStorage and every time the app opens you compare between the current version number and the number stored, if you found a difference then you will know the user updated.

Also you will need to install [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid) package

Here's how:

```js
import React from 'react'
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
    
// Your root class component
class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const lastSavedVersionNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem('appVersionNumber')
      if (!!lastSavedVersionNumber) { // Validate the value if it's really there
        if (lastSavedVersionNumber !== DeviceInfo.getVersion()) {
          // The user has updated the app because the numbers doesn't match
          // Set the new version number then logout
          AsyncStorage.setItem('appVersionNumber', DeviceInfo.getVersion())
          // ... logout here
        }
      } else {
        // Value doesn't exist, need to set it for the first time
        AsyncStorage.setItem('appVersionNumber', DeviceInfo.getVersion())
      }
    } catch (error) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great solution, thanks